# sp_whoisactive - Do stats include activity for snapshot versioning?

Tags: sql-server, sp-whoisactive

On a system that has read committed snapshot isolation enabled, do the reads, writes, CPU, etc. stats returned by sp_whoisactive include the activity associated with maintaining versions in tempdb?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe so, since none of the [common DMVs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms175492(v=sql.105)) used to track version store usage are present in the proc code.

Comment: Thanks Erik--I'm seeing massive read stats (in the millions) on sleeping sessions that have a transaction open (using implicit transactions).  I know that's bad, but it's vendor code and if we turn off implicit it blows up.  Are the crazy read stats due to running queries in implicit mode and never finishing a batch?

Comment: @TonyHinkle I might suggest posting more detail in the OP if you have a specific scenario in mind, but anecdotally [I have seen crazy reads blow up `sp_WhoIsActive`](https://twitter.com/tjaddison/status/1013764449843531776?s=21) in RCSI in some situations

Comment: @TonyHinkle I'd post that as a new question, since this one is limited in scope. Someone else may want to answer, etc.